# Server instantly skips pin search

Tags: c, sockets, passwords

I am trying to create two programs that send messages to each other using sockets following the *server-client* model.

The client is supposed to put a pin (in this case "1234") but the server for some reason skips the function `search4pin()`. I tried using `atoi()` to read the variable buffer and storing it to pin but it changed nothing. Using gdb I saw that the variable does not take a value. Thanks for your time.

Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define MAX_PINS 1

void error(const char *msg){
     perror(msg);
     exit(1);
}

int search4pin(int pin,int pins[]){
     for(int i=0;i<MAX_PINS;i++){
          if(pin==pins[i])
               return 0;
     }
     return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, pid;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    char* comm[20],*cbuff;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n,i,done=0,pin,correct=0,pins[MAX_PINS]={1234};
    char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    char* args;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No port provided\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR on accept");
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cli_addr.sin_addr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not convert byte to address\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "The client address is :%s\n", str);
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        sscanf(buffer,"%d",&pin);
    while(!search4pin(pin,pins)){
        n = write(newsockfd, "Wrong pin!\n", 12);
        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
    }
    /*Some other 
   code*/

    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
void error(const char *msg){
     perror(msg);
     exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3){
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
    (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
         error("ERROR connecting");

    printf("What is the password?\n");
    n = write(sockfd, stdin, sizeof(int));
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any output to this thing? it should be part of your question. Clearly you have error messaging and info messaging, so it's important.

Comment: looks like to me you're checking for the wrong condition in the `while` loop. `search4pin` returns 0 (false) if it finds a match. That 0 is banged `!` to true, so the loop body enters, and here you send "Wrong pin" even though there was a match on the pin. The `while` loop body is skipped if `search4pin` doesn't find a match (returns 1, this gets banged to 0).

Comment: That loop seems pointless anyway, since there is no modifier to the actual condition, and no `break`. The only thing that will break that loop is a socket-write error, and that's probably not intentional.